# Update refused: App not compliant with the Data safety section of User Data policy

Tags: android

Google refuses an app update and claims that I am collecting and sharing data (phone number, email address). Therefore, they want me to adjust the "Data safety" section in the Play Console.

As proof, Google sent me a screenshot of my app, which shows an input field that can be used to search a phone book....

Yes, in my app you can edit the phone book of an internet router, among other things. But this data remains on the smartphone or is synchronized end-to-end encrypted with the private customer's device. Neither I nor third parties have access to the data.

The Google policies says that in this case you don't collect or share any data at all and you don't have to specify this in the "Data safety" section:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdatenerhebung%2Cdata-collection%2Cdata-sharing

> **Not in scope for data collection**
>
> The following use cases do not need to be disclosed as collected:
>
> - On-device access/processing: User data accessed by your app that is only processed locally on the user’s device and not sent off device does not need to be disclosed.
> - End-to-end encryption: User data that is sent off device, but that is unreadable by you or anyone other than the sender and recipient as a result of end-to-end encryption does not need to be disclosed.
> - The encrypted data must not be readable by any intermediary entity, including the developer, and only sender and recipient may have necessary keys.

But as usual, Google doesn't respond to my objection and keeps sending me the notice to fix it and upload a new version of my app.

Of course, I could just say in the Play Console that I am collecting phone number and email address. But when I do this, it later shows up in the Google Play Store under my app and discourages customers.

This is very frustrating. Do any of you have any ideas?

Comment: did you find any solution for your case?

Comment: Google developer support, as usual, was no help. In the end, I simply made the input fields where Google suspects the collection of data inaccessible. Only when you have completely set up the app are the input fields visible. But Google would need a specific device for that. In the end, my approach worked and the app was released. But the actual problem was then only circumvented. My conclusion is that it makes no sense to write to support.